# jQuery array - duplicates are printed larger

Tags: jquery

I have this line of code

```
var songs = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
var songArray = jQuery.makeArray(songs);
$(songArray).appendTo(document.body);
```

Which looks for span tags on a page, creates an array then displays them. I don't know if that's the best way to do it but it works. But the problem I'm having is I want to display the array and if there is a duplicate in that array, it deletes the duplicate and increases the font size of the first instance of it. Not sure how to get that done.

Comment: you need to procide more info. Such as what constitutes a duplicate. T´Right now all we now is that they are all `span`s

Answer (score 0):

The below code will select all `span`s and add them to the body unless a span with the same "value" has been added in which case the font size will be set to `larger` however the function ´getValue` is left as an "exercise" due to the lack of information in regards to what constitutes a duplicate

```
var songs = $("span")
    temp = {};
songs.each(function(){
  var value = getValue(this);
  if(!temp.hasOwnProperty()){
     (temp[value] = $(this).clone())
       .appendTo(document.body);
  } else {
     temp[value].css({"font-size":"larger"})
  }
});
```